# Timeline serialization concept in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm not asking for a source code, wanted to know what concept will be done when serializing a video timeline which consist of layers?

Can anyone give me an idea?

I'm referring the timeline like in this picture:

[Picture](http://www.animemusicvideos.org/guides/avtech/images/premiere1.GIF)

Thanks for anyone who will provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Each layer appears to be a collection of objects each with a start and stop time.  If you had a collection class which was a collection of those layers, that class could be serialized.  This is far too broad though - *much* depends on what the layer class looks like and the layer items and which serializer you want to use. We have no idea of any of that.

Comment: Never mind I've managed to solve that problem thanks anyway. :)